# Why don't Node.js TLS supported ciphers correspond to the openssl supported ciphers?

Tags: node.js, security, ssl, encryption, openssl

According to `openssl`, these are the ciphers that it supports:

> ```
>  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
>  DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
>  AES256-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
>  EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
>  EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
>  DES-CBC3-SHA            SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
>  DES-CBC3-MD5            SSLv2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=MD5 
>  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
>  DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
>  AES128-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
>  RC2-CBC-MD5             SSLv2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=RC2(128)  Mac=MD5 
>  RC4-SHA                 SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
>  RC4-MD5                 SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=MD5 
>  RC4-MD5                 SSLv2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=MD5 
>  EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=DES(56)   Mac=SHA1
>  EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=DES(56)   Mac=SHA1
>  DES-CBC-SHA             SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=DES(56)   Mac=SHA1
>  DES-CBC-MD5             SSLv2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=DES(56)   Mac=MD5 
>  EXP-EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH(512)  Au=RSA  Enc=DES(40)   Mac=SHA1 export
>  EXP-EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH(512)  Au=DSS  Enc=DES(40)   Mac=SHA1 export
>  EXP-DES-CBC-SHA         SSLv3 Kx=RSA(512) Au=RSA  Enc=DES(40)   Mac=SHA1 export
>  EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5         SSLv3 Kx=RSA(512) Au=RSA  Enc=RC2(40)   Mac=MD5  export
>  EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5         SSLv2 Kx=RSA(512) Au=RSA  Enc=RC2(40)   Mac=MD5  export
>  EXP-RC4-MD5             SSLv3 Kx=RSA(512) Au=RSA  Enc=RC4(40)   Mac=MD5  export
>  EXP-RC4-MD5             SSLv2 Kx=RSA(512) Au=RSA  Enc=RC4(40)   Mac=MD5  export
> ```

I am running a simple node.js `https` server on port 443. When I run `sslscan`, the following are the `Accepted` ciphers:

> ```
>  Accepted  SSLv3  256 bits  AES256-SHA
>  Accepted  SSLv3  128 bits  AES128-SHA
>  Accepted  SSLv3  168 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA
>  Accepted  SSLv3  128 bits  RC4-SHA
>  Accepted  TLSv1  256 bits  AES256-SHA
>  Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  AES128-SHA
>  Accepted  TLSv1  168 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA
>  Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  RC4-SHA
> ```

**What I don't understand is, why is the list of actually supported ciphers so much shorter?**

What's even more confusing, when in node I get the list of supported ciphers `tls.getCiphers()` I find a long list:

> [ 'aes128-gcm-sha256',
>     'aes128-sha',
>     'aes128-sha256',
>     'aes256-gcm-sha384',
>     'aes256-sha',
>     'aes256-sha256',
>     'camellia128-sha',
>     'camellia256-sha',
>     'des-cbc-sha',
>     'des-cbc3-sha',
>     'dhe-dss-aes128-gcm-sha256',
>     'dhe-dss-aes128-sha',
>     'dhe-dss-aes128-sha256',
>     'dhe-dss-aes256-gcm-sha384',
>     'dhe-dss-aes256-sha',
>     'dhe-dss-aes256-sha256',
>     'dhe-dss-camellia128-sha',
>     'dhe-dss-camellia256-sha',
>     'dhe-dss-seed-sha',
>     'dhe-rsa-aes128-gcm-sha256',
>     'dhe-rsa-aes128-sha',
>     'dhe-rsa-aes128-sha256',
>     'dhe-rsa-aes256-gcm-sha384',
>     'dhe-rsa-aes256-sha',
>     'dhe-rsa-aes256-sha256',
>     'dhe-rsa-camellia128-sha',
>     'dhe-rsa-camellia256-sha',
>     'dhe-rsa-seed-sha',
>     'ecdh-ecdsa-aes128-gcm-sha256',
>     'ecdh-ecdsa-aes128-sha',
>     'ecdh-ecdsa-aes128-sha256',
>     'ecdh-ecdsa-aes256-gcm-sha384',
>     'ecdh-ecdsa-aes256-sha',
>     'ecdh-ecdsa-aes256-sha384',
>     'ecdh-ecdsa-des-cbc3-sha',
>     'ecdh-ecdsa-rc4-sha',
>     'ecdh-rsa-aes128-gcm-sha256',
>     'ecdh-rsa-aes128-sha',
>     'ecdh-rsa-aes128-sha256',
>     'ecdh-rsa-aes256-gcm-sha384',
>     'ecdh-rsa-aes256-sha',
>     'ecdh-rsa-aes256-sha384',
>     'ecdh-rsa-des-cbc3-sha',
>     'ecdh-rsa-rc4-sha',
>     'ecdhe-ecdsa-aes128-gcm-sha256',
>     'ecdhe-ecdsa-aes128-sha',
>     'ecdhe-ecdsa-aes128-sha256',
>     'ecdhe-ecdsa-aes256-gcm-sha384',
>     'ecdhe-ecdsa-aes256-sha',
>     'ecdhe-ecdsa-aes256-sha384',
>     'ecdhe-ecdsa-des-cbc3-sha',
>     'ecdhe-ecdsa-rc4-sha',
>     'ecdhe-rsa-aes128-gcm-sha256',
>     'ecdhe-rsa-aes128-sha',
>     'ecdhe-rsa-aes128-sha256',
>     'ecdhe-rsa-aes256-gcm-sha384',
>     'ecdhe-rsa-aes256-sha',
>     'ecdhe-rsa-aes256-sha384',
>     'ecdhe-rsa-des-cbc3-sha',
>     'ecdhe-rsa-rc4-sha',
>     'edh-dss-des-cbc-sha',
>     'edh-dss-des-cbc3-sha',
>     'edh-rsa-des-cbc-sha',
>     'edh-rsa-des-cbc3-sha',
>     'exp-des-cbc-sha',
>     'exp-edh-dss-des-cbc-sha',
>     'exp-edh-rsa-des-cbc-sha',
>     'exp-rc2-cbc-md5',
>     'exp-rc4-md5',
>     'idea-cbc-sha',
>     'psk-3des-ede-cbc-sha',
>     'psk-aes128-cbc-sha',
>     'psk-aes256-cbc-sha',
>     'psk-rc4-sha',
>     'rc4-md5',
>     'rc4-sha',
>     'seed-sha',
>     'srp-dss-3des-ede-cbc-sha',
>     'srp-dss-aes-128-cbc-sha',
>     'srp-dss-aes-256-cbc-sha',
>     'srp-rsa-3des-ede-cbc-sha',
>     'srp-rsa-aes-128-cbc-sha',
>     'srp-rsa-aes-256-cbc-sha' ]

Comment: [sslscan](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sslscan/) only tests for SSLv2, SSLv3 and TLS 1.0. So you will be missing all the TLS 1.2 cipher suites, like the GCM suites (TLS 1.1 did not add any cipher suites). The list of available will be further pruned with something like `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list("HIGH:!ADH");`.

Answer (score 3):

The first list are all the ciphers of SSLv3. Currently TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1 and TLS.2 have already been defined. So these are older ciphers.

The second list is the list of ciphers that are available in both client (sslscan) & server at the time of the handshake.

Finally, the last one seems to be the full list of ciphers that are present (but possibly not configured?) in NodeJS.

Note that OpenSSL documentation is notoriously sparse and often out of date, and that NodeJS does just slightly better.

Comment: Thank you. What I don't understand is, why is something like 'SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA' rejected when sslscan tried to connect with this cipher suite? I mean it is built on top of OpenSSL just like the node.js.

Comment: I presume that is mainly due to the current configuration and *possibly* the availability of matching keys (e.g. for DHE you need a key that is suitable for signing). I'm not sure how smart OpenSSL is in this regard.

Comment: Way late but DHE on nodejs/OpenSSL requires a signing cert _and_ dhparam values; see https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/tls.html#tls_perfect_forward_secrecy ; ECDHE only requires a signing cert which makes its omission more surprising to me.

Answer (score 1):

Node disables a lot of older, insecure ciphers by default. You can see the default enabled ciphers in the [node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_modifying_the_default_tls_cipher_suite) (note that this may vary depending on which version of node you're using).

As noted by jww, the legacy version of sslscan (which you seem to be using) doesn't support TLSv1.1/1.2, so won't detect some of the newer ciphers (like the GCM suites). The [updated version](https://github.com/rbsec/sslscan) does.